# kafka.common.KafkaException: Found directory E:\software\kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1\bin, 'bin' is not in the form of topic-partition

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

If a directory does not contain Kafka topic data it should not exist in Kafka's log directory

[image]

help~

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `server.properties` file such that there is no references to Kafka's extracted folder.

In particular, look at the `log.dirs` property

Comment: Note: Using a newer version of Kafka won't fix the problem, but will be more performant, and have less bugs

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but info does not expire

Thanks @OneCricketeer

I think the error means it can't find a place to put log files

Appending /logs to your log.dirs path seems to help (2) days with #Kafka don't judge